# Porting a MATLAB code to Python

Tags: python, matlab

**UPDATED TO REFLECT COMMENTS**

I am required to port a MATLAB code into python. Unfortunately, despite lot os sleepless nights of debugging and googling, I cannot get my code to run. Here is the MATLAB code in question:

```py
clc;
serie =0:50;
serie = serie - mean(serie);
y = cumsum(serie);
L = length(y);
%Calculate the detrended fluctuation short term coefficient
npuntos = 10;
f1=zeros(1,npuntos);
for n1=4:16
%Segmentation
seg =(1:n1:L);
%disp(length(seg))
yn = zeros(1,L);
    for k = 1:length(seg)-1
        yaux = y(seg(k):seg(k+1)-1);
        x = 1:length(yaux);
        A=[sum(x.^2),sum(x); sum(x),length(x)];
        C=[sum(x.*yaux);sum(yaux)];
        v=inv(A)*C;
        a=v(1); b=v(2);
        pen=a;
        ord=b;
        ytrend = pen*x + ord;
        yn(seg(k):seg(k+1)-1) = ytrend';
    end
f1(n1) = sqrt((1/seg(end)).*sum((y(1:seg(end)-1)-yn(1:seg(end)-1)).^2));
end
n1=4:16;
f1=f1(4:end);
p1 = polyfit(log10(n1(1:end-2)),log10(f1(1:end-2)),1);
alpha1 = p1(1);
disp(alpha1)
```

My attempt to translate the code into python goes as follows:

```js
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(start=0, stop=51, step=1)
data = data.transpose()
data = data - np.mean(data)
y = np.cumsum(data)
L = len(y)
# Estimate the value of alpha1

npuntos = 12
f1 = [0] * npuntos
for i, n1 in enumerate(np.arange(start=4, stop=16, step=1)):
    seg = np.arange(start=0, stop=L, step=n1)  # Potential error
    yn = [0] * L
    for k in np.arange(start=0, stop=len(seg)-1, step=1):  # Potential Error
        yaux = y[seg[k]:seg[k + 1]-1]  # Potential Error
        x = np.arange(start=1, stop=len(yaux) + 1, step=1)
        A = [[sum(x ** 2), sum(x)], [sum(x), len(x)]]
        C = [[sum(x * yaux)], [sum(yaux)]]
        v = (np.linalg.inv(A)).dot(C)
        pen = v[0]
        ord = v[1]
        ytrend = pen * x + ord
        yn[seg[k]: seg[k + 1] - 1] = ytrend
    f1[i] = np.sqrt((1 / seg[-1]) * sum((y[1:seg[-1] - 1] - yn[1:seg[-1] - 1]) ** 2))
n1 =np.arange(start=4, stop=16, step=1)
f1 = f1[4:]
xx =np.log10(n1[1: - 2])
yy=np.log10(f1[1: - 2])
print(len(xx))
print(len(yy))
p1 = np.polyfit(xx, yy, 1)
alpha1 = p1[1]
print(alpha1)
```

Unfortunately, I get TypeError when the program is executing this line

```
p1 = np.polyfit(xx, yy, 1)
```

This is indeed expected as xx is of length 9 while xx is just 5. By using try/catch block as suggested in the comment,

```
try:
    f1[n1] = np.sqrt((1 / seg[-1]) * sum((y[1:seg[-1] - 1] - yn[1:seg[-1] - 1]) ** 2))
except IndexError:
    f1.append(np.sqrt((1 / seg[-1]) * sum((y[1:seg[-1] - 1] - yn[1:seg[-1] - 1]) ** 2)))
```

the error is fixed by the output is completely wrong.

I have gone through the debugger but I cannot quite how the error. Can someone please help?
P.S -The above snippet is supposed to calculate the [Detrended Fluctuation Analysis (DFA)](https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/dfa/) if anyone is interested.

Comment: That I have tried but it gives me the same error. Do you mean something like this `f1[n1] = np.sqrt((1 / seg[-1]) * sum((y[0:seg[-1] - 1] - yn[0:seg[-1] - 1]) ** 2))`? This did not work either. I get the same `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you have `npuntos = 10` so that `f1 = [0] * npuntos` makes your `f1` `list`'s size equal `10`. And then you iterate over

```
for n1 in np.arange(start=4, stop=16, step=1):
```

And accessing `f1[n1]` which from 10 to 15 will give you an `IndexError`

**UPDATE**

First of all you can use `np.zeros((5,), dtype=np.int)` since you already using `np` module.

Secondly to figure out the thing with `IndexError`. Personally i don't want to fall into mathematical problem that you are solving, so the solution won't be the best. Just a slight change. I believe that you know that Python indexing is zero based. Since that you will start populating your at 5th element. I'm not sure that you want it. You can do `enumerate(np.arange(start=4, stop=16, step=1))` to create zero based indexing to your list:

```
for i, n1 in enumerate(np.arange(start=4, stop=16, step=1)):
    ...
    f1[i] = np.sqrt((1 / seg[-1]) * sum((y[1:seg[-1] - 1] - yn[1:seg[-1] - 1]) ** 2))
```

But `len(np.arange(start=4, stop=16, step=1))` is `12` not the size you creating your `f1`(`10`). So from that point you can create `12` element list.

```
npuntos = 12
f1 = [0] * npuntos  # or np.zeros((5,), dtype=np.int)
```

Or you can do `append`ing values as it done in MATLAB(as @nekomatic noted) if it's required.

So you need to wrap

```
f1[n1] = np.sqrt((1 / seg[-1]) * sum((y[1:seg[-1] - 1] - yn[1:seg[-1] - 1]) ** 2))
```

in `try / except`:

```
try:
    f1[n1] = np.sqrt((1 / seg[-1]) * sum((y[1:seg[-1] - 1] - yn[1:seg[-1] - 1]) ** 2))
except IndexError:
    f1.append(np.sqrt((1 / seg[-1]) * sum((y[1:seg[-1] - 1] - yn[1:seg[-1] - 1]) ** 2)))
```

Comment: Note that the MATLAB code does the same thing, but in MATLAB a matrix or vector automatically expands when you assign to an index outside its current bounds; the equivalent structure in Python (and most other languages) doesn't do this.

Comment: @nekomatic it's good to know.:) And that information is useful for OP.

Comment: @nekomatic, how to you suggest I go about solving this? I have tried to create an empty list and appending the values but I also get an error

Comment: @JohnP.Smith if the MATLAB code gives the correct result then your immediate error should be fixed by initialising `f1` with 17 elements, not 10 (17 because Python addresses them as 0…16). You should check whether there are any other changes you need to make for zero-based vs one-based indexing though. Also the fact that the MATLAB code contains this error would make me want to check carefully that it was actually implementing the algorithm correctly. I assume 4…16 are the intended values of `n` (the number of samples in each 'box' as described on your link)?

Comment: Also, by coincidence, I read a piece yesterday that cautions against jumping to conclusions about power law behaviour: http://bactra.org/weblog/491.html

Comment: @vishes_shell, Thanks for your suggestions. I have added your suggestion to my code. Unfortunately, it doesn't work yet. I have added my revision in my post if you care to take a look at it.